# Disk quota with a mounted folder and a new user

Tags: email, hard-drive, mount, quota

I have an email folder under /var/qmail/mailnames, with a file permission from the user popuser.

I would like to link the respective folder with the customer account.

for example:

Link or Mount?

Mail folder: /var/qmail/mailnames/exampleDomain -> /var/www/vhosts/exampleDomain/mail

User rights: popuser:popuser -> exampleDomainUser:exampleDomainGroup

The new mount point or link should be captured by disk quota.

I have already done a test with mountfs. The new folder is not recorded by Disk quota.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: I think you're asking if you can set up things so that you have a single fixed amount of storage for a customer which they can fill with either mail (owned by `UID=popuser`) or web content (owned by `UID=domainuser`)  or both in whatever fractions between 0-100% for mail and  the remainder  between 100 - 0 % for web content , as long as the total does not exceed your predefined quota limit.    Is that right?

Comment: Yes.

I have plesk on dedicated server. Plesk create an Folder with mails /var/qmail/mailnames/ with the user popuser. These files can not be assigned to the actual user with quota. Therefore, I am looking for a way to implement this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Create a LVM volume for each customer and point both the webroot as well as the mailstores there. Then you have hard quota regardless of which UID's get used.
- When you use  XFS you have the option to set what are called [*"project quota"*](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/xfsquota.html) where you assign different directories (and all the subdirectories and data therein) to a "project" and can maintain quota on those, i.e. create a *"project"* for each customer and add their webroot  /var/www/vhosts/example.com and their mail root /var/qmail/mailnames/example.com
- Learn to live with giving your customers a bit more then they expect, storage is cheap and simply set up independent quota for mail and webcontent.

Comment: I test the LVM option, thank! The other options are unfortunately out of the question. ZFS with Proxmox is not so simple. New storage space at SSD is quite expensive.

I will inform you about my results here.